# How to get all fields Leads from sales forces Using api

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am using sales force wsdl, and i need to get all fields created in leads in sales forces. Are the fields in sales force are always fixed for can be change or renamed.
please do reply.

Answer (score 0):

The developer names (API names) are fixed and can't be changed. However, be aware that people can create custom fields on objects which they name themselves (the API names always end in __c for these). They can also rename those at will unless they have apex code / Visualforce pages / formula fields etc. referencing those fields.

Comment: hi LacetSnr, thanks fro reply. when we add the WSDL in Visual studio we get certain classes with method and properties eg Lead.is there any way to get all the fields from sales force to make things dynamic. as if we add record by using properties that remain fixed.

Comment: You can get the fields in apex code dynamically so there _may_ be a mechanism, however I've not really utilised the web service APIs for standard objects much myself. If there aren't going to be any new custom fields added on Salesforce then you wouldn't have a problem just using the static list, if there are then you would need some other method I guess. It would be possible to write an apex class to implement a webservice which returns the list of fields on Leads quite easily.

Comment: See the partner WSDL, which provides a stable API regardless of schema changes made in the org.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using connector.describeSObjects("Lead"). This should return an object representing all fields in Lead. I don't know exactly how/what is returns in c#, I'm using salesforce-python-toolkit, and here is what I did:

```
result = h.describeSObjects('Lead')
```

This returned a large object describing all table relationships, an excessively large amount of info

```
print result[8]  #This was the index for Lead fields, with name, type, etc for each
```

I believe result is a two-dimensional array of hashmaps, not entirely since it didn't impact what I was working on.